# Solution Wide Dependency Resolution in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

Is it possible to enable Solution Wide Dependency resolution in Ninject or any other DI framework?

For example,

```
// different project, in the same solution :- ProjectLogging
namespace LogProject {
   public class Logger {
      [Inject]
      public ILogImplementation LogImplementation {get;set;}

      public void Log(string log, params object[] args){
        // .. implementation skipped
      }
    }
}

// in a different project, in the same solution:- ProjectA
namespace MainProject {
    public class Product {
         public static void Main(string[] args){
            new Logger().Log("Hello");
            // some magic here.. 
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Bindings());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Ninject personally, but I believe with structureMap you define your dependencies in the start-up project, and that information gets used for all projects within that solution - at least that's how it seems to have worked.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your example?  Generally DI containers operate per application instance, not per assembly.  As long as the container and the projects are aware of each other, it should work the same regardless of the project.  (Side note: If you don't want to couple all of your projects with the DI container you might look into something like a Service Locator to abstract the container.)

Comment: you do not really need to look into Service Locator, it's a total anti-pattern. You might want to use it carefully once in a while, when there's no better method, but generally, use Dependency Injection and IOC.
You can achieve just as much container independence without using Service Locator to abstract the container.

Comment: As far as the question goes, it's totally feasible, with all IoCs there are. Just remember that the composition root (==> the application, if you have multiple, you have multiple composition roots!) is responsible for creating bindings. Ninject offers `INinjectModule` to share bindings. You'll probably also want to look into ninject.extensions.conventions.